# Get-VMHost does not show the server Networkinfo and number of processes

Tags: vmware-esxi, powershell, virtual-machines, powercli

I run the following powercli 5.5 command , to get info about a host vm :-

```
Get-VMHost |Export-Csv -Path c:\VM.csv -NoTypeInformation –UseCulture
```

and I got these info :-

```
State   ConnectionState PowerState  VMSwapfileDatastoreId   VMSwapfilePolicy    ParentId    IsStandalone    Manufacturer    Model   NumCpu  CpuTotalMhz CpuUsageMhz LicenseKey  MemoryTotalMB   MemoryTotalGB   MemoryUsageMB   MemoryUsageGB   ProcessorType   HyperthreadingActive    TimeZone    Version Build   Parent  VMSwapfileDatastore StorageInfo NetworkInfo DiagnosticPartition FirewallDefaultPolicy   ApiVersion  Name    CustomFields    ExtensionData   Id  Uid
Connected   Connected   PoweredOn       WithVM  Folder-ha-folder-host   TRUE    HP  ProLiant DL365 G5   8   18400   1402    5M230-08JDM-J8R41-05NH4-2DR3N   16381.85547 15.99790573 13184   12.875  Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2356    FALSE   UTC 5.0.0   623860  host        HostStorageSystem-storageSystem localhost:  mpx.vmhba1:C0:T0:L0 VMHostFirewallDefaultPolicy:HostSystem-ha-host  5   172***.101  VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Util.ReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]  VMware.Vim.HostSystem   HostSystem-ha-host  /VIServer=root@***:443/VMHost=HostSystem-ha-host/
```

But I have these 2 questions:-

- under the `networkinfo` column I got the following `"localhost:"` instead of getting the host ip, mac, et.. so what is causing the Networkinf to not show the actual network info ?
- for the `NumCpu` column I got 8, which is the number of cores in our case. as in our case we have 2 processes with 4 cores on each processor. so my question is how I can get the number of processes (2 in our case) instead of getting the number of cores ?is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under the `networkinfo` column I got the following "localhost:" instead of getting the host ip, mac, et.. so what is causing the `NetworkInfo` to not show the actual network info ?

The `NetworkingInfo` property is actually an object of the [VMHostNetworkInfo](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/VMHostNetworkInfo.html) type, who's string representation is the host's 'Name' and 'Domain' glued together with a colon. This translates to what the *host* thinks it's hostname and domain are, and should be configured to match the FQDN.

You can change it with using the `Set-VMHostNetwork` cmdlet as outlined [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/Set-VMHostNetwork.html).

```
$vmHostNetworkInfo = Get-VmHostNetwork -Host Host

Set-VmHostNetwork -Network $vmHostNetworkInfo -DomainName eng.vmware.com -HostName Host1
```

> For the `NumCpu` column I got 8, which is the number of cores in our case. as in our case we have 2 processes with 4 cores on each processor. so my question is how I can get the number of processes (2 in our case) instead of getting the number of cores ?is this possible ?

It is possible, but you have dig a little deeper down the object structure of the host to get it. It's found in the  `ExtensionData.Summary.Hardware.NumCpuPkgs` property of a given VMHost object.

You can get it thusly:

```
$VmHost = Get-VMHost <hostname>
$HostSockets = $VmHost.ExtensionData.Summary.Hardware.NumCpuPkgs
```