# unable to get the IP,Mac, and other network info using (Get-VMHost).NetworkInfo

Tags: vmware-esxi, powershell, vmware-vsphere, powercli

I am using powerCLI verion 5.5, and I wrote the following script:-

```
Get-VMHost |Export-Csv -Path c:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation –UseCulture
```

I got info for the vmhost such as used memory, build, state ,cpu spped,  etc. but for the networkinfo section inside the generated .csv file I got "localhost" instead of the VMHost network info. so I wrote another script as follow to get the ip,mac and other netwrk info:-

```
(Get-VMHost).NetworkInfo | Export-Csv -Path c:\test2.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

but I got these info only , where I can not get the IP,MAC of the VMHOst :-

```
VMHostId    VMHost  VMKernelGateway VMKernelGatewayDevice   ConsoleGateway  ConsoleGatewayDevice    DnsAddress  DnsFromDhcp DnsDhcpDevice   DomainName  HostName    SearchDomain    VirtualSwitch   PhysicalNic ConsoleNic  VirtualNic  Uid IPv6Enabled ConsoleV6Gateway    ConsoleV6GatewayDevice  VMKernelV6Gateway   VMKernelV6GatewayDevice ExtensionData   ExtensionData2
HostSystem-ha-host  ******.intra    172.16.20.1                 FALSE           localhost       VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Interop.V1.Host.Networking.VirtualSwitchInterop[]   VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Interop.V1.Host.Networking.Nic.PhysicalNicInterop[] VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Interop.V1.Host.Networking.Nic.HostVirtualNicInterop[]  VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Interop.V1.Host.Networking.Nic.HostVirtualNicInterop[]  /VIServer=root@****************:443/VMHost=HostSystem-ha-host/VMHostNetwork=/   FALSE                   VMware.Vim.HostNetworkInfo  VMware.Vim.HostNetworkSystem
```

so can anyone advice how I can get the network info the vmhost ? and should this be done as a separate script or I can do this inside my original script Get-VMHost ??

Comment: Presumably you want the Host's MAC & IP address?

Comment: this this a hypervisor server,, and I need to get its ip , mac

Comment: and why when I write Get-VMHost I got "localhost" under the Networkinfo column ?

Comment: `and why when I write Get-VMHost I got "localhost" under the Networkinfo column ?`, because that's what configured on the host (regardless of what's setup in DNS), as stated [here](http://serverfault.com/a/711592/266218).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to use the `Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter` [cmdlet](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc/Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter.html).

In particular, using the `-VMKernel` switch to only get the host's management interfaces.

Something like this:

```
Get-VMHost <hostname> | Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter -VMKernel
```

Comment: ok this worked well thanks a lot. but to improve performance can I combine the "Get-VMHost" & "Get-VMHost <hostname> | Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter -VMKernel " into one script. so I can get the prevoiuse info + the networkinfo instead of having to run two separate scripts ?

Comment: I'm sure you can. You'd need to loop through all the hosts and create a new object with just the properties you want, append that object to an array and then print the array. Something like [this](http://kunaludapi.blogspot.ca/2014/11/powercli-vmhost-esxi-server-inventory.html)